# Core Data Stack structure

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, background-process, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am implementing a program in Swift and I am using the `Core Data` framework. My app is done but I have decided to refactor the Core Data Stack. Right now the structure of my `Core Data Stack` looks like this:

[image]

I took a look at the `Core Data Stack` form Big Ranch Nerd and some other guys on Github and most of the time, their `Core Data Stack` looks like this:

[image]

I wondered if there was a better way to refactor my `Core Data Stack` in a similar way. In a nutshell, this is what I am using my `Managed Object Context` for:

- `mainContext` = for all the UI-related task
- `firstPrivateContext` = for importing all the data from Firebase and pushing the data to the persistent store at Login
- `secondPrivateContext` = for importing the contacts from the device into Core Data at Login and Sign Up
- `thirdPrivateContext` = for listening to incoming data from firebase during the use of the app

So that is what my app is roughly doing. If someone knows a better way of doing, I am open to any suggestions.

This is the code I'm using when the user logs in again:

```
func importDataFromFirebase(){
guard let importContext = importContext else {return}
FirebaseStore.rootRef.childByAppendingPath("users/"+FirebaseStore.rootRef.authData.uid+"/forums").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock:{
    snapshot in
    guard let firebaseData = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else {return}
    guard let uids = firebaseData.allKeys as? [String] else {return}
    importContext.performBlock{
        for uid in uids{
            guard let forum = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Forum", inManagedObjectContext: importContext) as? Forum else {return}
            FirebaseStore.rootRef.childByAppendingPath("forums/"+uid+"/posts").queryOrderedByKey().observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: {
                snapshot in
                            // Saving the chat's messages
                            guard let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary else {return}
                            importContext.performBlock{
                    guard let posts = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Post", inManagedObjectContext: importContext) as? Post else {return}
                    do{
                                            try importContext.save()
                                        }catch let error{
                        // Error
                                        }
                }
            })
        }
    }
})
}
```

This diagram shows what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can build your CoreData stack in any way, but first answer the question - what behaviour you want to achieve.
If you want to update UI automatically when something got imported, then your solution will not work.

The whole point of having `private managed object context` right after `persistent store coordinator` is to keep heavy operation(saving to file) in background queue.

If you want to see updates on screen immediately after you import them, you should do import in `child private managed object context` which has `parentContext` set to `main managed object context`. And for updating UI you can use `NSFetchedResultsController`. This way whenever you do save in `child managed object context` - it will trigger notification which will be handled by `NSFetchedResultsController` and update UI.

Do not forget to save full stack. It's not enough to call save for `child managed object context` to save into file.

Suggest to write some method for saving full stack, like this one:

```
- (void)saveWithCompletionBlock:(void (^)(NSError *error))completionBlock {

    static dispatch_queue_t queue = NULL;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        queue = dispatch_queue_create("CoreDataSaveQueue", 0);
    });

    //Retain current NSManagedObjectContext to avoid unloading
    __block NSManagedObjectContext *strongSelf = self;
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        __block NSManagedObjectContext *context = strongSelf;
        __block NSError *error = nil;

        do {

            [context performBlockAndWait:^{

                if (context != nil && [context hasChanges])
                    [context save:&error];

                context = (nil != error ? nil : context.parentContext);
            }];
        } while (nil != context);

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if (completionBlock)
                completionBlock(error);
        });

        //Release current NSManagedObjectContext after save completed
        strongSelf = nil;
    });
}
```

I hope my explanation will help you understand how you want to build stack.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The behaviour I want to achieve is to first import all the data from Firebase and pushing it to the persistent store when the user logs in. Than, after he logged in, I want to display this data and to update UI automatically when gets added to Core Data or Firebase. I already implemented the last part, but I am struggling with the first part, sometimes all the data gets imported or only halve of it. My import is not robust at all. I think it is also related to the way I delete all my Core Data when the user logs out.

Comment: Did you figure out why only half of data got imported? How you doing import?

Comment: From your code I see that you are not calling save context after `for uid in uids`.
I'm not very familiar with Firebase, but as far as I understand those 
`FirebaseStore.rootRef.childByAppendingPath(…` will do async API call to fetch info you need. But you only saving after you get second API call response.
Also, are you sure that you should call `observeSingleEventOfType`? Will it return complete set of data?